# Lambda expression intellisense stops working when enclosed in a div element

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, razor, lambda, intellisense

I've come across a weird problem and that's literally driving me nuts. Suddenly intellisense stopped working on lambda expression when the code containing lambda is enclosed in a div. There's no problem when the code is placed outside div. Here're the pictures to see the difference

[image: The working case]

As you can see in the above picture @Html.DropDownListFor is not inside a div and when I type x there's the x inside the pop up and nothing is selected automatically. But if I enclose that same code inside a div the following problem will occur:

[image: The wrong one]

As you can see there's no x in the list and `XhtmlMobileDocType` is selected by default and when I type "=" after x `XhtmlMobileDocType` is entered automatically. I've done the same thing on another view and haven't had such an issue.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio is this? Which version of Razor?

Comment: Visual Studio 2012, Update 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hah, I found the problem. This must be some kind of a bug. There wassome code I had commented out below the code I showed you. If I take out that commented area the problem just evaporates.

[image]

And here's the one with commented out code:

[image]

Comment: Interesting. It might be worth noting that, if you open **and close** your parentheses before you go inside to create a lambda, the bug will not occur.

Comment: Hmm, that's true indeed. Guess this needs to be reported to VS team

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

**Remove equals** (`=`) so that auto-completion isn't **committed** when you press it. You can uncheck space bar's behaviour if you want.

[image: Visual Studio IntelliSense settings]

### Only happens on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>

I can only reproduce this problem when I force open intellisense with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> (default).

When I **open parentheses** and intellisense pops up for me, `XhtmlMobileDocType` is only faintly-selected and pressing `=` or space does nothing.

[image: Auto intellisense]

When I force open with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>, `XhtmlMobileDocType` **is** selected and will commit if I press `=`.

[image: Forced intellisense]

Comment: But still there's a problem because in two cases the contents of the pop up lists are different. The working one contains the x and nothing is selected by default, but the problematic one does not contain x and the first thing that begins with x is selected to be entered.